# Sharepoint 2013 Tag profile is empty

Tags: tags, sharepoint-2013

When I click on tag in tag clouds web part, I have a tag profile page (mysite.domain.com/tagprofile.aspx?termid=9e183a42-9603-43ea-8e9c-173e62dbe34c) which is empty.

How can I see the data in a tag profile?

UPD: If I click a search tag link, I have query like 
SocialTagId:"9e183a42-9603-43ea-8e9c-173e62dbe34c", but no data in result.
I found how to search for tagid, if write in search box query: owstaxIdTaxKeyword:"9e183a42-9603-43ea-8e9c-173e62dbe34c", we have all documents with this tagid.

But how to get result on TagProfile page?

Answer (score 1):

The Tag Cloud in SharePoint leverages social tags, not just any enterprise keyword. Though most tags are pulled from the Managed Metadata Service, social tags are stored alongside the User Profile Service Social Database.

You need to make sure that the library you are tagging documents have social tagging enabled. You do this by going to the **Library Settings** > **Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings**. Within there, you will be able to enable **Save metadata on this list as social tags**:

[image: Enable Social Tagging]

Then, make sure you are using the **Tags & Notes** board to ensure that your documents are tagged appropriately.

[image: Tags & Notes Board]

Finally, make sure that you Search Service application is actually crawling. If you have only performed an initial crawl, setup a crawl schedule or switch to using Continuous Crawling.